# Spring 5 Java Config Set Default Profile

Tags: java, spring

In my older Spring 4 web-app, I used an applicationContext.xml file, and my default spring profile was as follows;

```
<beans profile="default">
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:/opt/myapp/myapp-ws.properties" />
</beans>
```

And now I am using Spring 5 Framework, but NOT Spring Boot 2.x, and I want to do this in my Java Config class.

My main configuration class looks like this;

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.tomholmes.myapp")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyAppConfig
{

}
```

And I have the AppInitializer as follows;

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ApplicationInitializer.class);

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class[]
        { MyAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class[]{};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[]
        { "/api/*" };
    }
}
```

I've been doing some research on the Net since there is a lot of information on this, but a lot of it conflates Spring Boot,and I just want a Spring 5 without Spring Boot solution.   I'll keep looking, I am sure this is a simple issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this might do the trick:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {

@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();

    final List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
    resources.add(new FileSystemResource("/etc/app/application-{profile_1}.properties"));
    resources.add(new FileSystemResource("/etc/app/application-{profile_2}.properties"));

    ppc.setLocations(resourceLst.toArray(new Resource[]{}));
    return ppc;
}
```

Please note, that this is just the suggestion, this code is not tested.

Profile specific application properties should be resolved automatically by current active profile.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but a [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) class with both [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) and [`@PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) should work:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("default")
@PropertySource("file:/opt/myapp/myapp-ws.properties")
public class MyappWebservicePropertyConfig {
}
```